# ArrayLists (Removing and Changing Elements)

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello everyone I am an amateur in Java and had some specific questions about a program using ArrayLists. The program is made up of several classes, and its purpose is to add, change, remove, and display friends from a Phone Book. I have the add and display methods done, but I'm having trouble with the remove and change method.  I saw a similar case on this site, but it did not help me solve my problems. Any help at all would be much appreciated. This is what I have so far:

> 

```
package bestfriends;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BFFHelper 
{
    ArrayList<BestFriends> myBFFs;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public BFFHelper()
    {
        myBFFs = new ArrayList<BestFriends>();
    }

    public void addABFF()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a first name: ");
        String firstName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a last name: ");
        String lastName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a nick name: ");
        String nickName = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a phone number: ");
        String cellPhone = keyboard.next();
        BestFriends aBFF = new BestFriends(firstName, lastName, nickName, cellPhone);
        myBFFs.add(aBFF);


    }

    public void changeABFF()
    {
        System.out.println("I am in changeBFF");
    }

    public void displayABFF()
    {
        System.out.println("My Best Friends Phonebook is: ");
        System.out.println(myBFFs);
    }

    public void removeABFF()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a friend's name to be removed: ");
        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (i < myBFFs.size() && !found)
        {
            if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(myBFFs.get(i).getFirstName()) && lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(myBFFs.get(i).getLastName()))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }      
    }    
}
```

That was my Helper Class, for which I'm having trouble with the removeABFF method, and still need to create a changeABFF method from scratch. Next is my main class:

> 

```
package bestfriends;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BFFPhoneBook 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        int menuOption = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        BFFHelper myHelper = new BFFHelper();

        do
        {

            System.out.println("1.  Add a Friend");
            System.out.println("2.  Change a Friend");
            System.out.println("3.  Remove a Friend");
            System.out.println("4.  Display a Friend");
            System.out.println("5.  Exit");

            System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");
            menuOption = keyboard.nextInt();

            switch (menuOption)
            {
                case 1:
                    myHelper.addABFF();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myHelper.changeABFF();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myHelper.removeABFF();
                    break;  
                case 4:
                    myHelper.displayABFF();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option.  Enter 1 - 5");

            }



        } while (menuOption != 5);
    }   
}
```

This is my last class:

> 

```
package bestfriends;

public class BestFriends {

    private static int friendNumber = 0;
    private int friendIdNumber;
    String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    private String cellPhoneNumber;


    public BestFriends (String aFirstName, String aLastName, String aNickName, String aCellPhone)
    {
        firstName = aFirstName;
        lastName = aLastName;
        nickName = aNickName;
        cellPhoneNumber = aCellPhone;
        friendIdNumber = ++friendNumber;
       // friendIdNumber = friendNumber++;


    }

    public boolean equals(Object aFriend)
    {
        if (aFriend instanceof BestFriends )
        {
            BestFriends myFriend = (BestFriends) aFriend;
            if (lastName.equals(myFriend.lastName) && firstName.equals(myFriend.firstName))
               return true;
            else
               return false;
        }
        else
            return false;



    }
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getNickName()
    {
        return nickName;
    }

    public String getCellPhone()
    {
        return cellPhoneNumber;
    }

    public int getFriendId()
    {
        return friendIdNumber;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return friendIdNumber + ". " + firstName + " (" + nickName + ") " +  lastName + "\n" + cellPhoneNumber + "\n";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to explain what troubles you are having?

Comment: Sure, my removeABFF method is not working properly, as it seems to remove the element form the ArrayList, but when I go to display, it's still there. I apologize if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To explore and manipulate a arraylist an [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is used
>   the object lacks the Setters

declare variables

```
ArrayList<BestFriends> myBFFs;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
BestFriends best;
public BFFHelper()
{
    myBFFs = new ArrayList<BestFriends>();
    best= new BestFriends();
}
```

Delete

```
public void removeABFF()
{
    System.out.print("Enter a friend's name to be removed: ");
    String name= keyboard.next().toLowerCase();// entry name to be removed
    Iterator<BestFriends> nameIter = myBFFs.iterator(); //manipulate ArrayList
    while (nameIter.hasNext()){
        best = nameIter.next(); // obtained object list
        if (best.getNickName().trim().toLowerCase().equals(name)){ // if equals name
            nameIter.remove(best); // remove to arraylist
        }           
    }    
}
```

Update

```
 public void changeABFF()
{
    System.out.print("Enter a friend's name to be change: ");
    String name= keyboard.next().toLowerCase().trim();//entry name to be update
    Iterator<BestFriends> nameIter = myBFFs.iterator(); 
    while (nameIter.hasNext()){
        best = nameIter.next();
        if (best.getNickName().trim().toLowerCase().equals(name)){// if equals name
            best.setNickName("NEW DATE");//update data with new data Setters
            ....
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and I appreciate the quick response. Just one question, "best" is giving me an error in removeABFF, telling me to create it as a variable. Should I declare it as a String?

Comment: the variable best? or that variable?

Comment: Yes it's telling me best is not declared as a variable, and that I should declare it.

Comment: place in my answer how and where to declare, it is the inception of its kind

Comment: Alright I declared it, and now I should create a constructor for "BestFriends" in bestfriends.BestFriends(), correct?

Comment: if an empty constructor (without parameters) should always be that in a class constructor

Comment: That I do understand, but when I declare "BestFriends best" and then  "best = new BestFriends", it asks me to create a constructor of it in the BestFriends class. When I do that, the program still gives me an error when running:   Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: I was wrong to digitar is `nameIter.remove ();` instead of `myBFFs.remove ();`

Comment: Got it, now it's working, much appreciated. For the changeABFF, I am not seeing any changes when I choose display. For example, it asks me which friend I want to change, but it doesn't allow me to change it to anything.

Comment: you added your setters? as in the example code let NickName change your data should be changed, what a mistake has?

Comment: I apologize that was my mistake, it works perfectly now. I very much appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In your remove method you do not accept any input of the values

```
public void removeABFF()
{
    System.out.print("Enter a friend's name to be removed: ");
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    while (i < myBFFs.size() && !found)

    ....
```

As you are using `firstNamer` and `lastName` to find the object you needs these values

```
    System.out.println("Enter a first name: ");
    String firstName = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("Enter a last name: ");
    String lastName = keyboard.next();
```